# Ubuntu 16 No "Mail" program installed

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

Consistently when I have looked at Ubuntu installations, upon login, I have seen a notification like "You have new mail"

I am interested in how this works, how to both send and receive mail.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21334/how-do-i-leave-a-message-for-another-local-user) says that it should be as easy as typing `mail` to read mail you have received and `mail -s` to send mail.

However, when I try that on `16.04` I get the message

> The program 'mail' is currently not installed. To run 'mail' please ask your administrator to install the package 'mailutils'

Am I correct that I need to install `mailutils` to send both local (i.e. to another user) and external mail messages?

This looks like it also involves Postfix, do I need Postfix to use the local mail option?

Lastly, I asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810849/what-is-the-local-email-and-what-is-the-built-in-email-service-in-ubuntu-16/810857#810857) about programs such as `cron` that send a mail message to a user at certain points in time - if `mailutils` is not installed, is `cron` able to send any mail messages at all?

Comment: For external email have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/732782/57576 No POstfix needed...

Comment: alpine is a very easy command line mail client which runs from the CLI (command line interface) like `mail`.  The mailutils also installs postfix, which is part of a mail server.  Just be aware you probably can't e-mail out without the okay from your ISP.  Unless you run a VPS (virtual private server) in the cloud.  Even then, spam, spam, you gotta jump through hoops.  **yes, install mailutils**