# How to let crontab use s-nail to send emails?

Tags: cron, email-client

I am setting up a new Linux computer.  I installed s-nail (sudo apt install s-nail) to send emails from command line (and my scripts) to any email addresses over the Internet.  After adding the necessary lines to /etc/s-nail.rc with my gmail credentials for gmail SMTP server, things are now working properly.

There are no other packages installed on this computer (mail, mailx, sendmail, postfix, ssmtp, etc. are all absent).

But right now, I cannot get crontab to email me (at my gmail address) when cron job fails.  I don't really understand how things exactly work, but I guess s-nail does not need a local MTA while cron requires one?

Is there any way to get cron to email me, without installing any other packages?  Can I create symbolic links to mail, mailx and sendmail (all pointing to s-nail) in order to "fool" crontab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Make cron use `s-nail` as `mail`

cron has an internal mechanism to send job output to e-mail recipients. That mechanism expects an external program with the interface of `sendmail` ([see](https://serverfault.com/a/632265)) or, on Ubuntu, also apparently an interface of `mail` ([see](https://askubuntu.com/a/810857)). Probably, cron chooses the first of `sendmail` and `mail`, like other programs do ([see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728724)).

What does *not* work is to symlink `sendmail` to `s-nail`. The trouble is, `s-nail` is not compatible. `cron` will complain about an unrecognized custom header option `-S`, a missing mail body, or some such. Rather, the [author's webpage](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html#s-mailx) says:

> It is intended to provide the functionality of the POSIX mailx(1) command

The interface of `mailx` is however similar to `mail`! And indeed, a workaround seems to be this:

> You can make a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/mail` to `/usr/bin/s-nail`. [… M]ake sure that `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is not installed as it [will] first try to use `sendmail` [[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728724)]

These instructions are written for how to let the unattended-upgrades script use `s-nail` to send e-mails, but cron behaves the same way, so give it a try. (I did not try myself yet.)

### 2. Or use `s-nail` in individual cronjobs

If solution 1 from above does not work out and you *really* want to use `s-nail`, you can integrate the mailing of output into each of the commands that you want `cron` to execute. A `crontab` entry could look like this:

```
# every minute, execute your_command and send sterr by e-mail (but not stdout)
* * * * * { ./your_command > /dev/null ; } 2>&1  | s-nail -s 'A subject' target@example.com
```

Inspiration: a similar technique seen used with `mail` ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1396506), [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4594491)).

### 3. Or use `msmtp` or `ssmtp` instead of `sendmail`

If you are not yet sold on using `s-nail`, this alternative is a rather elegant and simple solution. For this, you let cron rely on the `sendmail` interface for mailing output, and install one of the modern `sendmail` alternatives that integrating most of the conveniences that `s-nail` provides (such as sending via external SMTP servers directly, without the need for a local mailserver).

`ssmtp` and `msmtp` are such programs. See [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/536934) for good instructions to use cron with `ssmtp`. When installing `ssmtp`, it will already install a symlink from `sendmail` to its binary.

But apparently, `ssmtp` is unmaintained now, and `msmtp` is its proposed successor ([migration guide](https://binfalse.de/2020/02/17/migrating-from-ssmtp-to-msmtp/)).